# setting up autocomplete on content type using profile2 and entityreference

Tags: entities, users

so, I'm creating a content type called "elearning", and I have some modules installed:

```
-ctools
-entity api
-entity reference
-profile2
-views
```

Then I create new profile called "teacher" with the field:

```
-full name
```

fields for "elearning" content type are:

```
-title (default)
-body (default)
-teacher: (with detail below)
field type : entity reference
widget : autocomplete
target type : profile
entity selection tab:
mode : simple (with optional by bundle)
target bundles : teacher
sort by : a field attached to this entity
sort field : full name (column value))
sort direction : ascending
```

I have one user with the role teacher, I gave the detail full name as "john pantau".

I created new content/node, when I tried to fill teacher field which is autocomplete, the list does not suggest from full name, I expected "john pantau" but not, it suggests "teacher" instead. after checking table, the suggestion ("teacher") is coming up from field "label" in table "profile".

what do I miss? I want to the suggestion comes up from full name field.
please help me.

thank you before.